# Flattening a list of lists, replacing empty sublists with a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, list, list-comprehension

I have list of lists which contains a mix of empty and non-empty sublists. 
The total length of the list is 240.

```
_remain = [['24'],
 ['24'],
 ['17'],
 [],
 ['17'],
 [],
 ['17'],...]
```

And I've tried to flatten the list of lists into one list with:

`[name for sublist in _remain for name in sublist]`

But when I do this I get a list with length 220. The empty sublists are gone.

My desire is to get a flattened list, replacing empty lists with `np.nan` so that I can insert it into a pandas `DataFrame`.

The resultant list I would like to get:

```
['24',
 '24',
 'np.nan',
 '17',
 'np.nan',
 '17',...]
```

What should i try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
>>> [name for sublist in _remain for name in (sublist or [np.nan])]
['24', '17', nan, '17', nan, '17']
```

Answer (score 2):

Since pandas is tagged(though this can be done with vanilla python as suggested by the above answer), one way is:

```
pd.DataFrame(l).fillna(np.nan).squeeze().tolist()
```

---

```
['24', '17', nan, '17', nan, '17']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option:

```
L = [
    ['24'],
    ['17'],
    [],
    ['17'],
    [],
    ['17']
]
L = np.array([l[0] if l else np.nan for l in L])
```

Output:

```
L >> ['24' '17' 'nan' '17' 'nan' '17']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a small helper function:

```
lst = [[1], [], [2], [], [3]]

def func(x):
    try:
        return x[0]
    except IndexError:
        return None

[func(i) for i in lst]
# [1, None, 2, None, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
 flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

or

```
flat_list = []
for sublist in l:
    if len(sublist) == 0:
        flat_list.append(np.nan)
    else:
        for item in sublist:
            flat_list.append(item)
```

Comment: It put two versions, one that handles nan and other that doesn't